# I am running python code and the class takes several minutes to run. Is there a way to pause the code mid-run and edit the code?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am running a class that takes several minutes. There are many times that it is about halfway done when I realize that I would like to print something. Is there a way to add in a print statement without having to stop the run and add it in if the specific function has not run yet? All I have really been able to find is sleep statements, but those would need to have been added before the run and I can't edit the code using a sleep timer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pause the execution of the code and overwrite the code to reflect the changes in the forthcoming execution steps. The python file is compiled into a `.pyc` file which is currently getting executed. Hence even if you manage to pause it somehow, the current execution will resume the execution of the previous executable itself. also the use of sleep function is not actually stopping the execution. The code is still executing.

A good way to go about doing this is to setup logical breakpoints in  your code rather than using multiple print statements throughout. You may have a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2019#:%7E:text=To%20set%20a%20breakpoint%20in,and%20select%20Breakpoint%20%3E%20Insert%20breakpoint.) or [this](https://realpython.com/python-debugging-pdb/) to know how to set break points. Although I would recommend using the VsCode debugger for the task.

Thus in conclusion, you cannot pause the script and make edits such that they reflect upon resuming the script's execution. Technically you can stall the execution of the script but that would never allow you  to achieve what you intend to do.

Comment: Thanks so much. I thought that was the case. Really appreciate the swift response!

Comment: If this helped you then please upvote and accept the answer. In case of anymore follow up questions please comment.

Answer (score 0):

The `print` statement is not your logger; use `logging` instead

Here are the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html

Here's a good example on how to use Logging: https://realpython.com/python-logging/

Start putting `logger` statements throughout your code.

> a way to pause the code mid-run

Yes, it's called a `breakpoint`. You'll need to set a breakpoint somewhere in your code. It can even be a `conditional breakpoint` in that the breakpoint only triggers when a certain condition is met.

You can then look at the variable values in your program's stack.

PyCharm is very good at all of this. I highly recommend it.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I'll check this out now!

Comment: If the answer helped, please upvote and if it is your preferred answer, please accept it as the answer. Thanks! And welcome to Stackoverflow.  :)